# How to remove character from files in folder in command?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have windows 7
I have a folder name employeephotos about 100 pictures that all have name_last.
I would like to remove all the "_" from the files in the folder and make the files namelast.jpg.

I have try this command

```
PS U:\desktop\employeephotos> Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name replace"_",""}

Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:18
+ Dir | Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName { $_.name -replace"_",""}
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (U:\desktop\employeephotos\New folder:String) [Rename-
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: oh great i run it on powershell , just getting different error

Comment: You might be missing a space after -replace. Also, this will fail if there is any file in the folder where `$_.name == $_.name -replace "_",""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From my comments)

1. Rename-Item is a PowerShell command, so you need to be working in PowerShell instead of the cmd.exe command prompt.
2. It might be picking up files with no `_` in the name, the rename does not change the name, and they cannot be given the same name, so it fails. Try `dir *_*` at the start to only find and rename files with `_` in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*_*" | Foreach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName $_.Name.Replace("_", "") -WhatIf }
```

If it produces the output you're looking for, then just pull the -WhatIf parameter off.